# Convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n^3+n^4}{2^{n+1}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Does $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n^3+n^4}{2^{n+1}}$ converges (absolute)?

I've already tried the Ratio test and the Root test test, but they failed both...

Comment: How did they fail?

Comment: Both tests work well.

Comment: using the ratio test: how can i keep doing reduce $\frac{1}{2}\frac{(n+1)^3+(n+1)^4}{n^3+n^4}$?

Comment: @fear.xD the Ratio Test is probably easier, and yes, it works.

Comment: @fear.xD : to answer your comment, your $k$'s should probably be $n$'s.  Divide numerator and by $n^4$ and take the limit as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: $\frac{1}{2}\frac{(n+1)^3+(n+1)^4}{n^3+n^4}=  \frac{1}{2}\frac{(n+1)^4(\frac{1}{n+1)}+1)}{n^3+n^4} =  \frac{1}{2}\frac{(n(1+\frac{1}{n})^4(\frac{1}{n+1)}+1)}{n^3+n^4}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{n^4(1+\frac{1}{n})^4(\frac{1}{n+1)}+1)}{n^4(\frac{1}{n}+1)} = \frac{1}{2}(1+\frac{1}{n})^4  \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: When both test fail, although in this problem that's not the case, and you have polynomial in the numerator and exponent in the denominator you can always use geometric series to find the value of convergance. Actually on one of your other question I showed you how to do it. This way it's little more complicated. This sum converges to 176.

Answer (score 4):

Hints:

(1) For $\;k\in\Bbb N\;$ :

$$a_n:=\frac{n^k}{2^n}\implies\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(n+1)^n}{2^{n+1}}\frac{2^n}{n^k}=\frac12\left(\frac{n+1}n\right)^k\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac12<1$$

(2) Comparison

$$\frac{n^3+n^4}{2^{n+1}}\le\frac{n^4}{2^n}\;\ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT, Root Test:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sqrt[n]{\frac{n^3+n^4}{2^{n+1}}}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\frac{n^3+n^4}{2^{n+1}}\sim \frac{n^4}{2^{n+1}}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sqrt[n]{\frac{n^4}{2^{n+1}}}=1/2<1
\end{equation}
with $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]n=1$

Answer (score -1):

Hint:
For each c>0, there exists $n_0$ s.t. if $n>n_0$ then $n>c\log(n)$ (by calculate the limit of $log(n)/n$) , then for $c=10$
you gets $2^\frac{n}{2}>n^5$, and by sum of geometric sequence you gets $n^5>n^4+n^3$ then...

Now, you can use comparison.